A Faustian Riddle
I crafted a riddle! It requires some knowledge of algorithms and video game culture to solve. With the hints, specialized knowledge isn't necessary. I imagine it's not terribly difficult, but it's hard to tell.
The riddle poses two questions to be answered, the second of which requires the naming of two things. All the answers are embedded in a story of a Faustian bargain and an existential realization.
so, first comes the devil
he offereth a deal
round then comes the question
a robin or a steal?
and if I'm what he offers
demand that I'm first served
lest I be a lie
what am I...?
alas, just algorithms
this I regress to learn
hail to those who c!
which are we?
_ _ _ e

_ _ _ _ _ - _ _ _ _ n

_ _ _ _ _ - _ _ _ _ - _ _ _ _ _ - _ _ _ _ _ d

Oblique hint for part 1:

 If that's what he's serving, you won't be eating any.

Another oblique hint for part 1:

 "This?" taunts he, "is not a piece of it."

Oblique hint for part 2:

 Can't see the trees for the forest.

Another oblique hint for part 2:

 Right on time, Satan flips you the bird.

(Maybe) Biggish hint:

 At least one line of the poem and all the oblique hints have both literal and idiomatic interpretations/allusions.

Certainly biggish hint:

 The non-algorithmic object to be guessed features in well-known sayings in English and in a popular phrase from a famous video game. Its oblique hints allude to those sayings.

Certainly another biggish hint:

 The fourth hint points to something in the poem to look at to make way in finding the algorithmic answers.


I feel I should add some hints, but I can't find how to create those redacted texts that you can read when pressing them. Any pointers? 8D Unless that's a puzzle in itself.

The way to figure out how to do anything at all that you see done in a post is to: Click the edit button on that post, read the raw code as written, scroll down and click cancel (to exit the edit screen). There's a list of sandboxed questions which are just right for that purpose. You can try out your markdown in the dedicated formatting sandbox. (I've forgotten how to do spoiler text, but it's easy to find out if necessary).

Ah, got it. Add >! then a space before each line.

Thank you so much! Now with hints.

Aside: the spoiler syntax is fussy, and at times goes wrong, for reasons I've never pinned down. When it does, I find the best solution is to start over: I can never correct my 'fault'.

Alright, this post has had quite a number of views with no guesses forthcoming. I have grown weary of waiting as well ;D Here are the intended answers.
1st answer:

 CAKE

"No hints" process:

 The answer is taken from the iconic phrase "The cake is a lie" from the 2007 video game Portal. The game's antagonist promises cake for completing increasingly dangerous tasks, but the promised reward turns out to be a lie. This relates to the Faustian theme of not getting what you thought you would.

The 2nd part of the poem relies on double meanings and near-homophonic readings to either paint a scene of existential pondering or to instruct towards the solution.
"just algorithms"
scene: just in the sense of only
guide: just in the sense of fair
"this I regress to learn"
scene: "I regret to learn"
guide: Go back over the first part of the riddle to figure out the solution.
"hail to those who c"
scene: "hell to those who see"
guide: A salute to programmers
2nd answer:

 ROUND ROBIN

3rd answer:

 FIRST COME FIRST SERVED

"No hints" proces:

 The solution is to discover the names of the two scheduling algorithms by looking at the words rather than the meaning. This relates indirectly to the existential theme of not finding meaning.

Explaining hint 1:

 This alludes to the saying "You can't have your cake and eat it too". Again, this relates to the Faustian theme that in a deal with ol' D, you don't come out with a net win.

Explaining hint 2:

 This alludes to the idiom "a piece of cake". To a surface reading, it looks like ol' D is doing nothing to help you, but he actually gives a hint and says that solving is going to be difficult.

Explaining hint 3:

 This indirectly instructs in finding the solution by looking for the right words among those in the first part of the poem.

Explaining hint 4:

 The surface reading seems to be ol' D being vulgar, but he's actually instructing you to look for a word related to birds that stands out (robin), as well as saying that the solution has something to do with timing and being right. The function of robin in the poem is to be read as robbing, the colloquial term for robbery. This gives the line the reading "a robbing or a steal?" in the idiomatic sense of "is the deal a rip-off or a bargain?". An alternative non-idiomatic reading is that you are going to be on the losing end in either case.

